# How easily can asics be ported over to other sha algorithms?

Tags: mining-hardware, sha256

Let's say I want to rewrite the software behind the hardware of current asics. Would it still mine, for example, sha1 algorithms orders of magnitude faster than a normal cpu would?

Comment: What do you mean by "the software behind the hardware"? The hardware cannot be changed, it is designed specifically for SHA256

Answer (score 2):

Application Specific Integrated Circuits are hard set to only do one thing, and in the case of bitcoin ASICs, that's SHA256 hashes. You cannot re-write the software, you would need a new circuit built that only does SHA1 or whichever hash you're looking for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit